# How to inherit only a method of a class, not the whole class itself (C++)

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have two classes - `Deck` and `Player` with the following structure:

```cpp
class Deck {
public:
    //constructors, destructors, operator=

    void addCard(const Card &card);

    bool changeCard(const unsigned int &index, const Card &card);

    void clearDeck();
    //other things

private:
    std::vector<Card *> cards;
};
```

```cpp
class Player {
public:
    //constructors, destructors, operator=

    void changeCardInDeck(const unsigned int &index, const Card &card);

    void addCardInDeck(const Card &card);

    //other things

private:
    std::string name;
    Deck *deck;
};
```

As you can see, since the `Player` class has a `Deck` member, it contains identical methods with the `Deck` class. But doing things like:

```cpp
void Player::addCardInDeck(const Card &card) {
    this->deck->addCard(card);
}
```

doesn't seem straightforward, so I am looking for a more direct way to do this.
However, inheriting the `Deck` class seems odd and I suspect that having a member of type pointer to an object of the parent class might cause some problems. So the question is: can I inherit only the methods I am interested in from the Deck class instead of doing the things mentioned above?

Comment: No, the design is correct. There shouldn't be a "more direct way". A Player has a Deck (don't know why you use a pointer, but whatever). And when a player "adds a card to the deck" he puts it in the deck that he has.  He is not a deck himself e.g puts the card in his a$$. P.s. although there could be a reason, a vector of Card *pointers* doesn't make much sense. Use as little pointers as possible!

Comment: It is somewhat possible with private inheritance + using-declarations. However, sometimes it's not even necessary to encapsulate the member (`Deck *deck`): if the `Player` does not protect any invariants, exposing the `Deck` is also an option (`Deck& Player::getDeck()`)

Comment: @dyp then you could as well make it a public member. But it's not necessary and imho bad design.

Comment: I use a vector of pointers instead of a vector of objects, because the `Card` class actually has two children classes. I omitted this information because it wasn't relevent to the question. The vector should store cards of different types and instead of making two vectors of objects, I made one vector that could store all cards.

Comment: @JHBonarius Exactly, members which don't need protection from class invariants can be public. I don't consider that bad design :) Or rather, not a bad implementation of a given design.

Comment: @JHBonarius I should add that I consider it a design smell if you have a class which has invariants but also a member on which it has no invariants. That suggests to remove the member which has no invariants (split the class into two).

Comment: Maybe you could use a `std::variant<CardTypeA, CardTypeB>` instead? Indirection/inheritance is not always the best solution. But anyhow, you could just do it the way it is. It's prolly not optimal code, just an exercise.

Comment: @JHBonarius Wow, I had never seen this before. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you current design is fine, however if you really want to, you can make methods you don't want to be able to access in your deck class, **private**, if you have some class which wants to be able to access that private method, you make that class a **friend** class.

Comment: That's not always a good design... you should "keep your privates to yourself". And note that friendship is **not** inherited.